# js recursive function changing variables unexpectedly

Tags: javascript

Here is a function I wrote in Javascript to illustrate the problem I'm having.

```
function test(x,depth){
    for (n=0;n<x;n++){
        console.log(x.toString()+" "+depth.toString()+" "+n.toString())
        test(x-1,depth+1)
        console.log(x.toString()+" "+depth.toString()+" "+n.toString())
    }
}


test(4,0)
```

here is my console output:

```
4 0 0  
3 1 0  
2 2 0
1 3 0
1 3 0
2 2 1
3 1 2
4 0 3
```

why is the variable n effected by calling test(x-1,depth+1)?
n is not passed as a parameter.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `n` is a global variable because it is declared without `let`, `var` or `const`. It is actually `window.n`. Means that each recursive called function uses the single property. Declare it via `let` or `var` to make each function has its own `n` variable.

```js
function test(x,depth){
    for (let n = 0; n < x; n++){
        console.log(x.toString()+" "+depth.toString()+" "+n.toString())
        test(x-1,depth+1)
        console.log(x.toString()+" "+depth.toString()+" "+n.toString())
    }
}


test(4,0)
```

Answer (score 3):

`n` is global, created via [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)* the first time you assign a value to it (`n=0`), and so that one global variable is used by all calls to `test`. You need to *declare* it within `test` for it to be local (and thus for each call to have its own copy). (E.g., add `var` or, in ES2015+, `let`.)

---

* *(That's a post on my anemic little blog.)*